# Any information about the photo with Army Uniforms

Tags: cultural-history, identification, poland, photography, europe

Found an old photo and want to identify which period does it belong to and where it could have been taken or which country are these soldiers from. Found word "Brattig" on the other side, maybe someone can tell me what it means?[image: Photo I found]

Comment: [Brattig](https://forebears.io/surnames/brattig) is apparently a surname from Germany.

Comment: I'm just glad I never met the guy who is seated.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

These are [Polish Army Uniforms](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_Armed_Forces), starting around 1919.
Unfortunately the main wiki pages show no Uniforms of the times.

To my knowledge, these types of [zig-zag collars](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barwy_broni_i_s%C5%82u%C5%BCb_Wojska_Polskiego_II_RP) (Polish only, but translates well to English) were in use sometime after 1918 until 1939 and are also unique to the Polish Army.

Other [photo collections, without dates](https://forum.odkrywca.pl/topic/756630-10-pu%C5%82k-u%C5%82an%C3%B3w-litewskich/) show the simularity of the Uniform jacket, collars and caps.

The caps called [Rogatywka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogatywka) are also unique to the Polish Army and are still in use today.
During the Warsaw Pact days the caps and collars were used only for ceremonial occasions.

An estimated date: 1919-21, possibly during the [Poland - Soviet war](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish%E2%80%93Soviet_War)

Comment: Minor correction: there was no Soviet Union until 1922, the  Polish-Soviet war was with the Soviet Russia (RSFSR)

Comment: The date seems overly exact for the reasons given. Other dated pics: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/May_Coup_(Poland)#/media/File:Pi%C5%82sudski_May_1926.jpg and in the gallery 1936 https://www.yadvashem.org/yv/en/exhibitions/communities/mir/between_two_wars.asp

Comment: @LangLangC Sorry, have no idea what you mean. Which date and which 'reasons given' from where? Such comments, in this form, are difficult to answer (if at all).

Comment: @jmster Sorry, have corrected text based on given wiki usage. Excuse is only that when I was in Poland between the 1970s to 1990s that is what we (in our respective languages) called it.

Comment: I meant your final estimated date and Russo-Polish-War. I see nothing in the picture or your arguments, cap, puttees, collar, etc that says pre1922, as all that was 'active' until 39. Unless you can point explicitly to sth I overlooked, I'd date the photo to interwar period. / Perhaps noteworthy. If the word Brattig indicates 'German name' then the amount of newly-Polish German draftees might be interesting…

Comment: @LangLangC The quality of the photo is the main reason for the range 1919-21. Also the type wrapped lower leggings, instead of boots, is typically WW1 style. As to the name, many Germans have polish sounding names, just as many Poles have german sounding names. So I dont the name will be of great assistance.

Comment: @LangLangC my polish jis not good enough to read any original polish documentation. Looking for a reference about boots, leggings will probably be the key for a proper dating togeather with photo style.

Comment: Well, pending more info or better resolution pic: the chinstrap on the cap has sth I suspect significant, but I can't make it out. If you have (pref: online/shareable, even it's just a pointer/ref) access to original Polish docs, include them in the A or in comments? (Eventually, someone might help out with the lang-barrier)

Comment: The *Wickelgamaschen* or puttees are typical WWI, but no exclusion criteria either, as they were redesigned as **M1936** pattern in the Polish army. They were worn even in the Polish contingent of the Soviet forces in 1941 and only completely phased out near the end of the war. The name is only a hint anyway as it is of Polish/Slavic origin but in a (East-)Germanised form. https://polishgreatness.blogspot.com/2012/04/world-war-2-military-uniforms-polish.html

Comment: @LangLangC Yes, it seems they were mainly used for the infantry, where many other branches used a form of riding boots. So the brownish color of the photo wouuld be the only hint of early 1920, since after that grey would be normal.

Comment: For the text look for a number that ends with 'r'. That is how years are written in Polish (like 1920r).