# Can someone identify this military uniform?

Tags: military, identification, uniform

I would really appreciate it if someone could tell me anything about this military uniform. Thanks so much for any help!
[image: man in military uniform]

Comment: Any other info you have about the photo, such as where and when it was taken (even if it's only a decade and country)?

Comment: Sorry, but I don’t know many particulars but I appreciate your help. I’m assuming it’s German, Russian, or Polish (during the Polish-Soviet war) based on my family heritage

Comment: @ThomasBy Thanks so much!

Comment: Have a look at this question about polish uniforms: https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/53980/any-information-about-the-photo-with-army-uniforms/53981#53981

Answer (score 6):

It seems to be Polish.

https://dobroni.pl/fotka-historyczna/14000

This drawing I found shows a uniform that has more accessories, and this may lead to confusion. I assume your photo pictures a young private with low or no grades.

Another picture of a Polish soldier clearly shows similar numbers on the collar:
https://ar.pinterest.com/pin/510173464030294530/?nic=1

Answer (score 3):

This is the Uniform of the Polish "Blue Army" which was a contingent which belonged to the French army and therefore received its name due to receiving French model 1915 uniforms. This unit consisted of men from all around the world of Polish ethnicity and this unit formed in 1917 fought on the Western front in World War one and would later be involved in the Polish-Soviet war. This unit by the end of ww1 would number 68,500 men.
Here are some some photos of the soldiers and uniforms.
[image]
[image][image]