# Are these Polish WWI or WW2 uniforms? And any idea on the shorter gentleman's military decoration (cross?) on left shoulder?

Tags: world-war-two, world-war-one

Can anyone identify these uniforms and the military decoration that looks like an x or a cross on the shorter gentleman?

[image]
The shorter gentleman is my great-grandfather. The only information I have is his name. I don't even have his DOB or DOD (although I'm speculating circa 1880's - 1940).  My ancestry is all Polish so thus the assumption for Polish uniforms. I've also researched that medal and seem to keep coming back to the cross of valor that was introduced in 1920. Lastly, my family comes from South of [Tarnow, Poland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarn%C3%B3w). Please see original image at imgur.com/a/ePZRfVO. Thank you!

Comment: Well they are certainly not Polish WWI uniforms as Poland did not have a military for the duration. But there was a decent bit of fighting with the USSR immediately afterwards.

Comment: Thank you @SPavel that helps narrow it down a bit more.

Comment: Can we get a rundown of everything you know about this image? (Why you might have suspected the unis to be Polish, for example). That can save our users lots of time, which could well get repurposed into making the answers better.

Comment: @T.E.D. Absolutely, although I don't have very much info. The shorter gentleman is my great-grandfather. The only information I have is his name. I don't even have his DOB or DOD (although I'm speculating circa 1980's - 1940).  My ancestry is all Polish so thus the assumption for Polish uniforms. I've also researched that medal and seem to keep coming back to the cross of valour that was introduced in 1920. Lastly, my family comes from South of Tarnow, Poland.

Comment: This answer https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/53980/any-information-about-the-photo-with-army-uniforms has useful links to an archive of Polish interwar uniforms. They all have distinctive squiggly collars that this photo lacks, making me think that these are not Polish after all.

Comment: Can you nail it down any better than simply "Polish"? Like cities or areas of the country? As @SPavel mentioned, at the start of WWI, Poland had been partitioned between The German Empire, The Austro-Hungarian Empire, and the Russian empire for a bit over a century.

Comment: I only know the origin of my family roots from that side of the family to stem from Lekawica (a Village south of Tarnow, Poland.) I believe the area used to be called Galicja which was under the Austro Hungarian Empire.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## This is almost certainly an Austro-Hungarian infantry private's uniform

During WWI, Tarnow was a part of Austria-Hungary, and mobilized Poles from that area into the army (including Polish Legion/Polish Auxiliaries).

The hat on the table in the corner resembles an infantry [field cap](https://nestof.pl/en/products/great-war-1914-1918/austria-hungary-1918/feldmutze-m1908-austro-hungarian-field-cap-repro-9496.html). It has what looks like a feather sticking out of the top, which is a common feature of Austro-Hungarian mountaineers (although the individuals are not mountaineers, as they lack the flower collar insignia).

The belt buckle looks like the [Dual Monarchy one](https://www.jbmilitaryantiques.com.au/product/ww1-austro-hungarian-army-unifrom-leather-belt-buckle/).

Additionally, the shape of the cross and ribbon looks like a [mobilization cross](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobilization_Cross_1912/13) or [long military service cross](https://www.medals-orders.com/austria-hungary-wwi-cross-military-long-service-12-xii-years-2nd-class-nco-1890-1913-medal-kaiser-kuk-austrian-hungarian-decoration-ww1-1914-1918-great-war-p909.html) (or a similarly shaped medal such as the Austrian [Iron Cross of Merit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_of_Merit_(Austria-Hungary)#/media/File:%C3%89rdemkeresztek_(Ausztria).jpg)) worn in the Austro-Hungarian fashion [high up on the chest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaiserj%C3%A4ger#/media/File:Franz_Josef_I_in_Kaiserj%C3%A4geruniform.jpg).

The color of the ribbon is a little bit confusing because the Iron Cross of Merit was introduced in 1916, but is being worn with a solid red ribbon which is the rule for being awarded in peacetime (as far as I can tell, no other Austro-Hungarian cross-shaped award was properly worn on a solid color ribbon).

I have not been able to find an exact match for them (it seems that the collar and cuffs should be [another color](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infanterist)), but if someone unfamiliar with the uniforms had colorized them, they might not have known this (edit: from comments by OP this appears to be the case, as AI colorization is essentially guesswork).

Comment: After the OP mentioned some family being in AH territory, I checked and the shirt does indeed appear to be a shape and configuration that matches an AH uniform. See pictures [here](https://www.facebook.com/ww1incolour/photos/a.450835521726972/2696782083798960/?type=3) and [here](https://www.warhats.com/store/p1129/WW1-Austrian-Hungarian-Cap-Pre-1907-into-WWI-Common-Army-Landwehr-Honved.html#/). The pockets with flaps with curved-down corners seem quite distinctive

Comment: [This picture here](https://www.reddit.com/r/coolguides/comments/tchs8n/evolution_of_uniforms_of_austrohungarian_habsburg/) seems to indicate that the darker color was in use from 1872-1905. The high collars appear to have been red, but that might not be showing well in this largely monochromatic image. The hat on the table I'd say most resembles the lighter shade of the depicted 1895 field cap. (Feel free to slurp any of these pictures into the answer if they look useful.)

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much for that information! I looked more into Austro-Hungarian military uniforms and found an image on this page that shows a similar uniform with the round "badge" on the right side here: https://www.alamy.com/english-uniforms-of-austro-hungarian-army-8-july-2011-112737-29-austro-ugarske-odore-image211461597.html . The translation states:  Cavalry Marksman with a machine gun. I have never seen any of the uniforms to have that round badge on them till now! Btw the image was colorized via software to help solve the mystery. Could that cross shaped medal be the cross of valour?

Comment: @KasiaLee - Calvary would make sense, as it also explains the boots outside the pants, which isn't typical from the images I've seen. I was thinking about mentioning that.

Comment: The soldier in [this illustration](https://www.whistlestoppers.com/the-habsburg-empire/the-austro-hungarian-forces-in-world-war-i-volume-1) has the chest-badge but is not cavalry. I wonder if that's a mistake.

Comment: Thank you so much SPavel! I have wondered about this for so long and until I stumbled on this website my research wasn't going very far. With just this post and your help, I found out so much about my Great-grandfather. Thank you again! I know this last question is a long shot but any idea how to date the image to any sort of estimated dates?

Comment: @KasiaLee It would help to have an unaltered version of the photo (the original black and white), in the highest resolution you have available. Unfortunately, AI tools such as colorization and upscaling are not reliable and can alter the original in a misleading way.

Comment: @SPavel The image seems too large to upload in the original question section and adding it to this comment doesn't result in it showing up. I'll keep trying.

Comment: @T.E.D. I missed your comments, but see them now. Thank you so much as well for your help! The images are amazing to see and its all coming together :).

Comment: @T.E.D. in regards to the 1895 field cap. Would those have been reused at all after 1895? My great-grandfather married his wife who was born in 1896 and he has 1 brother I'm aware of DOB 1893 so I'm assuming my great-grandfather's dob wouldn't be before 1880 and thus a hat from 1895 would make him 15 in the picture at best. Also if that medal is an indication of 12 years of service in the military, it 
 furthermore makes me wonder if his not around age ~32 in the picture.

Comment: @KasiaLee You can try using an external host like Imgur or Google Drive and then sharing a publicly accessible link

Comment: @KasiaLee - I'm just going by the picture, but from that the darker hat doesn't appear in those pictures again for another 10 years. I'm not an expert on how that picture was constructed, but I'd like to think you get a new image when the uniform changes, so it would have been the lighter cap for the entire intervening decade, not just the first year.

Comment: @SPavel https://imgur.com/a/ePZRfVO Hope this works.

Comment: I am watching a documentary on youtube that describes the hat in the picture as Feldkappe with black leather visors that was put into "service" in 1915 and replaced by 1917 by helmets!

Comment: @KasiaLee Thank you for the original image. I recommend adding it to the original question in case anyone has further insights. For my part, I couldn't squeeze any more detail from it in Photoshop than can be seen already. This makes me confident that the medal is indeed the iron cross of bravery, awarded in peacetime.

Comment: @SPavel Would you kindly share with me the photoshopped version on imgur? And again Thank you SO MUCH for all your research. This is truly amazing and a wonderful addition of information to the family tree I can pass down to my newborn son :).

Comment: @KasiaLee Sure - I was mostly screwing around with the light balance settings to see if I could reveal any additional detail at the very extremes, rather than making it look better, but it does benefit from a quick brightness/contrast adjustment and removing a few blemishes to the photograph https://imgur.com/a/OE9JlMz

Comment: @SPavel Thank you! It looks great!